# Erro Django: Invalid block tag: expected 'endblock'

Tags: python, django, django-templates

No ambiente de desenvolvimento funciona normalmente, já no servidor de produção tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Invalid block tag: 'ultimos_produtos', expected 'endblock'
```

Segue o trecho do código:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load shop_tags i18n %}

{% block meta_title %}{% trans "Home" %}{% endblock %}
{% block title %}{% trans "Home" %}{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumb_menu %}
<li class="active">{% trans "Home" %}</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}

<h3> Em destaque </h3>
{% ultimos_produtos "perfumes" "span2" 3 %}

{% endblock %}
```

Estou usando Django 1.8.16, Mezzanine 4.0.1.

A unica diferença entre os ambientes é que o ambiente de produção usa python 2.7.6 e o de desemvolvimento python 2.7.8

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Você fez o upload da pasta templatetags? Reiniciou o servidor?

Comment: Não tenho experiência com tags customizadas, mas uma coisa que noto quando se trata de templates em geral é que é necessário usar `manage.py collecttemplates` em produção - enquanto no ambiente de desenvolvimento isso não é necessário. Tiro no escuro, mas talvez ajude...

Comment: Por favor, mande o código do arquivo "base.html"